# remove tags which javascript returns with the text

Tags: javascript, html

here's my function

```
    function getInfo(Description) {


        return Description;    


}
```

here Description has

```
<p>Info Summary:<span>2.26PM</span> InfoADDED</p>
```

now, i want to **eliminate** html tags before returning the 'Description'
pls. help

Comment: which server side language are u using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what has worked for me

```
return Description.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, " ").replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
```

above CMS ex is also good
but this is what fitted best for me

Answer (score 2):

You could use a *dummy* DOM element, set the description as the `innerHTML` and later get its `textContent`, that will take out all the tags, and it will handle all the HTML Entities like `&nbsp;`:

```
function getInfo(description) {
  var tmp = document.createElement('div');
  tmp.innerHTML = description;

  return tmp.textContent || tmp.innerText;
}

getInfo('<p>Info Summary:<span>2.26PM</span> InfoADDED</p>&nbsp;');
// returns "Info Summary:2.26PM InfoADDED "
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/ilixu/2).

Comment: Isn;t it better to use a hidden existing div rather than creating new divs for each function call.

Comment: Well, it would be maybe even better to store a `div` element in a clusore and reuse it, as the elements don't need to exist in the DOM. Like this: http://jsbin.com/ilixu/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regex to strip the tags.

```
function getInfo(Description) {
  return Description.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");
}
```

Comment: what about the characters like &nbsp; and others..?
how to avoid them

Answer (score 0):

A foolproof way of doing this would be to iterate through each node and extracting the string inside the text nodes and concatenating them.

If you have an option of using jquery. the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function in jquery does this for you.