# jquery .text() returns html tags, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT: I am using Firefox 3.1+ specifically, as this is an intranet application.

I have the following html:

```
<em id="work-resize">re-size: from <span id="work-resize-from">3</span> to <span id="work-resize-to">5</span></em>
```

Using jQuery I want to get the following string:

```
're-size: from 3 to 5'
```

I assumed that using `.text()` would do exactly that, however:

```
$('#work-resize').text();
```

returns:

```
're-size: from <span id="work-resize-from">3</span> to <span id="work-resize-to">5</span>'
```

I peaked around, and I couldn't find out why. I could use a function as suggested here [remove tags which javascript returns with the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174884/remove-tags-which-javascript-returns-with-the-text), but I really thought that the point of `.text()` was to strip out the tags, so it seems redundant to use my own function. Does anyone out there have a better solution, or suggestion if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure? I just checked it, and the return value you're describing sounds a lot like `.html()`:

```
$('<em id="work-resize">re-size: from <span id="work-resize-from">3</span> to <span id="work-resize-to">5</span></em>').text()
"re-size: from 3 to 5"

$('<em id="work-resize">re-size: from <span id="work-resize-from">3</span> to <span id="work-resize-to">5</span></em>').html()
"re-size: from <span id="work-resize-from">3</span> to <span id="work-resize-to">5</span>"
```

Comment: Ugh. I found the error, I had the wrong thing selected. Deleting question now. Thanks for the super fast response though.

Answer (score 1):

yes friend. that's what i thought. i could no way reproduce this error.

see here. http://jsfiddle.net/Vu5ck/1/

next time use  http://jsfiddle.net something like that to report javascript problems.